# excel formula for searching string across columns and filtering results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an excel formula that allows me to filter results searching across all columns and sheets in my document.

For example, let's say my excel file has two sheets (**Sheet1** and **Sheet2**) with the following data:

**Sheet1**:

```
A       B       C
Col1    Col2    Col3
foo     1       NA
bar     2       y
baz     3       bar
foo     4       z
bar     5       NA
baz     6       foo
```

**Sheet2**:

```
A       B       C
Col1    Col2    Col3
foo     7       bar
bar     8       bar
baz     9       bar
foo     10      z
bar     11      y
baz     12      NA
```

I can write the formula:

```
=FILTER('Sheet1'!A:C;ISNUMBER(SEARCH("foo";'Sheet1'!A)))
```

which will return:

```
foo 1   NA
foo 4   z
```

However, I cannot find a way to filter the results taking into account all columns and sheets:

```
foo     1       NA
foo     4       z
baz     6       foo
foo     7       bar
foo     10      z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will certainly need `VSTACK()` & `MMULT()` to accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _DataFromBothSheets, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C7),
     _Include, MMULT(1-ISERR(SEARCH("foo",_DataFromBothSheets)),{1;1;1}),
     FILTER(_DataFromBothSheets,_Include,""))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function helps to define variables and makes easier to read.
- Using `VSTACK()` function, we are appending the data from both the sheets into one.
- Using `ISNUMBER()` or `1-ISERR()` which does the same to return `TRUE` for matched values and `FALSE` for error values because of the `SEARCH()` function which returns the position of the start of text.
- Using `MMULT()` to return the matrix product of two arrays here one returned  using the above and `{1;1;1}`
- Lastly, the above is the **include** argument of the `FILTER()` function when placed gives the desired output.

---

If its only a word you are trying to find and not within text strings, then you could do it in this way:

```
=LET(
     _DataFromBothSheets, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C7),
     _Include, MMULT(N("foo"=_DataFromBothSheets),{1;1;1}),
     FILTER(_DataFromBothSheets,_Include))
```

---

Or could use `BYROW()` a `LAMBDA()` helper function which applies a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to each row in the array and returns one result per row as a single array.

```
=LET(
     _DataFromBothSheets, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C7),
     _Include, BYROW(_DataFromBothSheets,LAMBDA(x, SUM(--(x="foo")))),
     FILTER(_DataFromBothSheets,_Include))
```

---

Also, in `Modern Excel` Versions, there is a new update for `Office Insider` users, if you happen to enabled it, then the `LAMBDA()` construct is not required for `BYROW()` as well, these are called `eta-LAMBDA()`

```
=LET(
     _DataFromBothSheets, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C7),
     _Include, BYROW(N("foo"=_DataFromBothSheets),SUM),
     FILTER(_DataFromBothSheets,_Include))
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Nice to see MMULT being used ;)

Comment: @HappyPy I am kind of not sure, how you get an error because i am using a valid name only. See i have updated with a screenshot showing the same. Kindly refer my formula bar. it spills the output

Comment: @HappyPy so is it working now with the expected outputs?

Comment: @HappyPy basically the solution is just one line, i have used longer variables so it becomes easier to understand. `=LET(_Data, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C7), FILTER(_Data,BYROW(N("foo"=_Data),SUM),""))` Thanks & glad to know it worked on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
`=LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:C,1),3),FILTER(w,BYROW(w="foo",LAMBDA(b,OR(b)))))`

Or if you have access to beta insiders: `=LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:C,1),3),FILTER(w,BYROW(w="foo",OR))))`

Note that it only works if all columns contain data in each row.

Comment: Thanks, this answer also works great (+1)! Is there a way to filter by partial match though, like `w="fo"`? The formula above only works if the cell contains the whole string: `w="foo"`. I tried fitting the SEARCH function, but have been unsuccessful so far...

Comment: Try changing `w="foo"` into `ISNUMBER(FIND("fo",w))`. Or instead FIND SEARCH to make it case insensitive